# How to get the training error while training with Caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, caffe

I'm training a simple neural network with Caffe, from the MNIST example. I need two things while training:

1. The classification error on the training set each 600 iterations
2. The classification error on the test set at the end, after 30000 iterations

Is that possible ?

I found out how to do 1) by replacing the test set by the training set and using `test_iter`, but it seems really hack and then I cannot have 2). Is there a simple way to tell Caffe to compute the training error on each `display` iteration for instance ?

Comment: the training error you see is the average on the minibatches, not the entire set.

Comment: Yes, but I need the error on the entire dataset after each 600 iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Maybe you can add a test phase in your `.prototxt` file and use
   `Accuracy layer` to output the accuracy.
2. Using `test_interval: 600` to set the test interval.

Comment: I added a second phase, and now I have the train accuracy during training, but the problem is not that I have the test and train accuracy at each 600 iterations. But it seems that is the best I can do.

Comment: It's probably the best that can be done In Caffe with multiple test phases so I selected this answer.